# Deploy Kubernetes on Self-host Production environment

Tags: kubernetes, self-hosting

I am trying to install kubernetes on Self-hosted production environment running on Ubuntu 16.04. I am not able to find any helpful guide to setup production grade kubernetes master and connect worked nodes to it.

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the kubespray to self Host production environment.

https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you understand by saying "self-host". The most people think it's about deploying kubernetes in the own environment.

If you want to compare different approaches to deploy k8s in a custom environment, refer to [this article](http://stytex.de/blog/2017/03/26/kubernetes-private-cloud-deployments-comparison/) which covers a bunch of options suitable for that.

If you are interested in how to set up an HA Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm, refer to [this article](https://medium.com/@bambash/ha-kubernetes-cluster-via-kubeadm-b2133360b198).

However, in kubernetes, there is a different definition of "self-hosted". It means running kubernetes itself as a workload in kubernetes. If you are interested in a real self-hosted approach (on a custom environment), refer to [this article](http://stytex.de/blog/2018/01/16/how-to-recover-self-hosted-kubeadm-kubernetes-cluster-after-reboot/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use [typhoon](https://github.com/poseidon/typhoon) which can be used to provision an HA kubernetes cluster.

Here is a sample configuration which I used to bring up my own [home cluster](https://github.com/tasdikrahman/infra/tree/master/aws/ap-south-1/homelab/poseidon).

A few advantages of typhoon are that you have the option of choosing your choice of a cloud provider for provisioning your infrastructure, which is done using terraform and the fact that it gives you upstream k8s is a big plus too.

Internally, it uses [bootkube](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/bootkube) to bring up the temporary control plane, which would consist of

- api-server
- controller-manager
- scheduler

and then when we have the temporary control plane object, we inject the objects to the API server to have our k8s cluster.

Have a look at this [kubecon talk given by CoreOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIZ8NaR7msI) which explains how this is working.

Comment: Shameless plug, I tried explaining the same in blog post if you like a textual approach to it. https://tasdikrahman.me/2019/04/04/self-hosting-highly-available-kubernetes-cluster-aws-google-cloud-azure/